# nested list filtering without changing object type in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, lambda, collections, filtering

I want to filter nested lists with kotlin without changing the object type.

```
data class ExamResponse(
    val list: List<ExamObj>
)
```

```
data class ExamObj(
    val objList: List<ExamObj2>
)
```

```
data class ExamObj2(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)
```

For example, I want to get the list 'ExamObj' with age value 27 for the above model.
The method to return the list is as follows.
`fun progress(respList: List<ExamObj>): List<ExamObj>{}`

this method takes a list of 'ExamObj' and filters the 'objList' in 'ExamObj' and returns the 'ExamObj' list again

```
val result = respList.map {
        it.objList.filter {
            it.age == 27
        }
    }
```

Using this I achieved the desired result but the type issue appeared.

[image]

Comment: Please read and keep in mind: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question For example, I know the answer, but don't want to take the time to have to retype your code from scratch to  do a minor edit to show the fix.

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot to wrap filtered `ExamObj2`  list in a `ExamObj` class...

```kotlin
val result = respList.map { examObj ->
    ExamObj(examObj.objList.filter { it.age == 27 })
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you can't really "filter" the list because it's wrapped in an `ExamObj` object. If you want to make a change to that list, the result needs to go in a new `ExamObj` (assuming you don't want to make the lists mutable, or make `objList` a `var` so you can just swap the filtered list in)